Fourier coefficients of powers of sinus
It is easy to compute the Fourier coefficients for the function $|\sin t|$, or $|\sin t|^3$ and maybe any integer exponent, but I couldn't find something for the function $|\sin t|^p$, where $p$ is a positive real number. If it is not possible to give a closed formula for it, is it possible to find information for them? Are they positive?

You want a general, closed form formula?  That's unlikely to exist.  For example, neither Maple nor Wolfram Alpha find a formula for $\int_0^\pi \sin(x)^{1/3} \cos(2 x); dx$.

@RobertIsrael I had also tried the Wolfram Alpha without success. However, wolfram can compute this numerically, and it seems that for p\leq 2, the fourier coefficients are negative.

Of course, numerical computation of individual coefficients can always be done using standard numerical integration software.

@RobertIsrael Yes of course. I was looking for a closed formula. If there is no such as you said, is it easy prove that the coefficients are negative for $p\leq 2$?

The relation 5.12.5 from https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12 gives the answer.
